# Compactness of a special kind of Integral operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $(S(t))_{t>0}$ be a continuous operator from $L^2(0,1)$ to its self and Let $K$ be the operator $$\eqalign{
  & K:{L^2}(0,1) \to {L^2}(0,1)  \cr 
  & f: \to (Kf)(x) = \int\limits_0^1 {k(s,x)S(s)f(s)ds}  \cr} $$
where $$k \in {L^2}(0,1) \times {L^2}(0,1)$$
It is well known that if $S=I$ then K is compact operator.
What can I say about the compactness of $K$ is this case?
Thank you.

Comment: There is no reason why the integral exists under the given hypothesis.  You need more hypothesis on $(S(t))$

Comment: What do you mean by $k \in {L^2}(0,1) \times {L^2}(0,1)$? Did you mean $L^2(0,1)^2$?

Comment: Yes. It is a $L^2$ kernel.